# function wrapping in c - sbrk for tcmalloc

Tags: c, tcmalloc, uclibc

I am trying to port tcmalloc to uclibc. Tcmalloc has a definition for sbrk function, which in turn calls the __sbrk from libc. Uclibc on the other hand does not have __sbrk function, but has sbrk.

Any ideas about how I can call uclibc sbrk from tcmalloc sbrk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sbrk](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) is a (old) [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), but most memory allocators are built above [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997425/how-are-sbrk-brk-implemented-in-linux)

You should use the syscall, not emulate it. And I would prefer using `mmap`, not `sbrk`

Doing a system call (usually `mmap`) is the only way to get more memory from the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel).

From the application's (or library's) point of view, a [system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) is atomic (it is mostly a single machine instruction like `SYSCALL`, `SYSENTER`, `int 0x80` etc.).

Comment: `sbrk` may be more useful then `mmap`, since the latter can fail to grow in-place.

Comment: `mmap` gives you indepedent segments of memory. I'm not sure to understand when you need to grow in-place. And there is also `MAP_GROWSDOWN` and possibly `MAP_NORESERVE`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504358/841108

Comment: You probably don't want to call `mmap()` for every bit of memory you want to allocate. Usually small memory requests are handled via `sbrk()`, while larger ones use `mmap()`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: yep, you can use any flags you please with `mmap`. `sbrk` memory mapping base address, on the other hand, is positioned in such a way that it can grow a lot before colliding with any other mapping.