# Does Linux gcc support coreleft function?

Tags: linux, memory, process

I read in article http://www.ousob.com/ng/borcpp/ng916c4.php about obtaining unused brk memory by calling coreleft(). But looks like that doesn't work on Linux. And also the file alloc.h doesn't exist. 
My question is that is alloc.h function family standard for Linux? If it doesn't, any alternatives for function like coreleft on Linux? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you care? Please **edit your question** to motivate it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can't speak for the OP but if you're curious, I ended up here by googling about a function that showed up in a very old DOS program. I took a guess that the function was outdated, and  that it wouldn't work properly in a virtual memory system, and from the looks of it, I was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to measure *memory usage* and this is very ambiguous on Linux. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224016/50557) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16586388/841108) for more. You'll want to use `/proc/`  pseudo-file system, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Remember that [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) use [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). See also http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Asking how much memory is left (or could be allocated, e.g. by [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...) does not make any sense, because some *other* process might release memory resources which would become later available for your process. Hence **there cannot be any *reliable* `coreleft`  function** -measuring available heap memory, e.g. for future calls to `malloc`- **on Linux (or POSIX)**. Both `mmap` & `malloc` can fail (and you should always check that).

You can limit many resources (including [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) or [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space)) on a process, see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) and the bash shell `ulimit` builtin.

The `sbrk` syscall is nearly deprecated (and no more used) on Linux. You'll get fresh virtual memory segment using `mmap` (and you release it using `munmap`). The [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implements [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) (from `<stdlib.h>`) by calling `mmap` appropriately; it usually tries to reuse previous `free`-d memory zones. On Linux with [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), see also [malloc_info(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html), [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html), [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html). You might study the source code of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) standard C libraries like [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) to understand more about them.

The `<alloc.h>` header is non-standard and does not exist on most Linux or POSIX systems.

If you need to reserve some address space *without* consuming memory (i.e. swap area) consider the `MAP_NORESERVE` option to `mmap`. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504358/841108).

In C on POSIX systems (like Linux), the usual habit is to use `malloc` (or related `calloc`) function, and to handle the out-of-memory case (which is unlikely to happen in practice, except on very loaded systems or when strong small limits have been set), perhaps by exiting with an error message:

```
 size_t siz = some_size();
 void* p = malloc(siz);
 if (!p) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28779266/841108) (suggesting Boehm's GC).

I suggest you to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)